# Creation of Pipelined SQL/NOSQL Queries in Java

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-integration

I am trying to create a framework in Java which would support chained/pipelined queries wherein the Output of one query would be transformed to be used as input of another queries. Something like [PyCascading](https://github.com/twitter/pycascading) These queries will be made at runtime. I looked upon some frameworks and came upon [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org)
& [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) as they provide concept of Chaining and routing(Enterprise Integration Patterns). I found Apache Camel better than Spring Integration(IMHO).

---

Should I go for Apache Camel for my framework or is there a better way I can achieve this?

My Query Syntax would be

```
Query query1 = "select customer.id from customer where customer.name = 'ABC'";
Query query2 = "select account.id from account where account.custid in {$1}";
// $1 will be the input of second query
from(query1).inputto(query2).printOutput();
```

Comment: I would chain the SQL statements in SQL `select account.id from account, customer where account.custid = customer.id and customer.name = 'ABC'` Pulling data out of a database just to pass it back again sounds inefficient.

Comment: I agree that would be a better way but my sql tables are going to be in distributed databases and it maybe SQL or NOSQL. So, the query object would be taking care of execution.

Comment: I would keep all the data which is likely to be joined logically together.  I would only put unrelated data into different databases if possible. I would try to only have one or two databases which will give you everything you need.

Comment: I agree that would be my model too but my frameworks wishes to cater to a need where the different units have their own databases(like HR, Finance, Sales) and have some common identifier.

Comment: That is reasonable, but I wouldn't encourage it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using [camel-jdbc](http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html) and a few basic Camel features (like [simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html)) to allow you to inline the result parsing...

> The [CAMEL-JDBC] result is returned in the OUT body as an ArrayList[HashMap[String,Object]]
>   The List object contains the list of rows and the Map
>   objects contain each row with the String key as the column name.

This result can then be used to dynamically construct subsequent queries...

```
from("direct:start")
  .setBody(constant("select customer.id as ID from customer where customer.name = 'ABC'"))
  .to("jdbc:myDataSource")

  //now, use simple/ognl to extract the first result and the 'ID' from the Map in the body
  .setBody(simple("select account.id from account where account.custid in ${body[0][ID]}"))
  .to("jdbc:myDataSource")

  .log("ACCOUNT IDS = ${body}");
```

Comment: Can I somehow pass my object instead of relying on the toString method in setBody() or is there a way where I can use Objects?

Comment: you can use Processor or Bean to do anything you want inside a route...see http://camel.apache.org/processor.html, http://camel.apache.org/bean.html